# Why hasn't this tag with 0 questions been deleted?

Tags: support, bug, tags

When reviewing the [list of tags on Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=name), I noticed a strange tag named [100-completion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/100-completion).

[image: Tag search page with 100-completion]

[Clicking on the tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/100-completion) reveals that there are 0 questions which use this tag. Trying to view the tag info page leads to a ["*Page Not Found*" error](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/100-completion/info), and the tag does not appear in the tag auto-complete suggestions when asking a new question.

Why does this tag with 0 questions show up in the tag search? Shouldn't it have been auto-deleted?

Comment: I added the bug tag since this seems to be a bug that you found. I noticed that if you hover over the tag from tag page, the small "Edit" link does not appear for it either.  Something odd is going on with it.

Comment: I can't remember exactly where I read it, likely a M.SE post, but IIRC its a 'feature' so if the tag is ever recreated the synonyms will still exist. Of course tag deletion & recreation is more common on sites that still remove tags with only one question. Even if that's the case,  we can remove orphaned synonyms fairly easily. I'll leave this one until we get official word from SE though.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't an answer (I don't think), but it may give some clues as to why it's there.

So I fiddled around with the SE Data Explorer, and found using [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/774574) that this is a tag synonym for the tag "completion."  Sure enough, if you search for "100-completion" within [tag synonyms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms), you will see it there. However, the tag "completion" does not appear to exist.  You will get the [Page Not Found](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/completion/synonyms) error like before if you click on the tag.

Bottom line, this appears to be a tag synonym for a deleted tag.  I'm guessing if a tag gets deleted, its synonym tags do not, hence why this one is still here.

Comment: This seems like a good bug report for [meta.se].